# PHP return echo in conditions

Tags: php

I have this block of code:

```
case 'forgot' :

        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){

            $returnArray['response'] = 'Please enter username or email.';

        } else {

            $tokenArray = $userClass->createToken($connection, $_POST["username"]);

            if(empty($tokenArray))
            {
                echo json_encode($userClass->sendUserResetEmail($connection, $_POST['username']));
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode($tokenArray);
            }

        }

    break;
```

This works, but it looks very messy, I am looking for away to have it more cleaned up like so:

```
case 'forgot' :

        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){

            $returnArray['response'] = 'Please enter username or email.';

        }

        $tokenArray = $userClass->createToken($connection, $_POST["username"]);

        if(empty($tokenArray))
        {
            echo json_encode($userClass->sendUserResetEmail($connection, $_POST['username']));
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode($tokenArray);
        }


    break;
```

My question is, if that first condition is true, how can I prevent more code from doing anything else, like stop after the echo in the condition.

Comment: If you mean after `if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){` use `break;`.

Comment: Add `return` or `break` inside if block. But still, both version of your code can be refactored further.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara How so?

Comment: Extract code and put them as separate method

Comment: use `return false;` before `if` or `else` code block ends